# Prompt customization problem with if clause

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters, terminal-emulator

I recently tweaked a bit my PS1. The code as follows:

```bsh
PS1='$(if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then echo " \e[91m\e[0m"; fi) \u $(assemble_prompt)$ '
```

The missing char is from [nerd-fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) and doesn't matter in my question (as well as `assemble_prompt` function).

The problem I encountered is a broken PS1 when I shrink terminal window size to the size of a prompt (approx.). Then it seem to ignore PS1 setting and sets PS1 to `$` chars only (see screenshot). Note then when I start typing it simply overrides my custom prompt in this occasion.

[image: PS1 went bananas]

I narrowed the problem to an if clause that adds "fail" char if previous command was unsuccessful. If I remove that part everything works as expected.

Is there a way to keep `if` clause part but fix the issue with PS1 reset when the window size is too small?

P.S. I use `rxvt-unicode` as my terminal but the problem persists in all other terminals also (tested `xterm`, `st`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to enclose the terminal control codes in `\[...\]` to tell Bash that they aren't actually printing characters. Otherwise they will confuse the shell when tries to count how wide the prompt is.

So use `"\[\e[91m\]xxx\[\e[0m\]"`.

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html):

```
\[  Begin a sequence of non-printing characters. 
    This could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt.
\]  End a sequence of non-printing characters.
```

Comment: Damn, that fixed the problem. Thanks! I missed that point about making them not printable.