# Cannot get .bashrc PS1 configuration to render without issues

Tags: bash, prompt

I essentially know what the problems is, in that I need to use `\[...\]` as a way to escape (non-space?) characters, and allow bash to correctly calculate the width of my prompt.

However, I cannot iron out all the problems and have been using trial and error as I don't quite understand where exactly I need all my `\[...\]` placed.

```
STARTCOLOR='\[\e[0;31m\]'
ENDCOLOR='\[\e[0m\]'
BACKGROUND='\[\e[47m\]'
export PS1="$STARTCOLOR$BACKGROUND\u@\h \[\t\]$ENDCOLOR\w>\$?\$\]"
```

Is what I am using. The only issue now seems if I use the arrow keys to scroll previous commands for too long the `\w>\$?\$\` part of my PS1 will disappear. It happens too if I reverse back with arrow keys after moving forward with previous commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the non-printing markers for something that gets printed out (`\t` - the timestamp)

```
STARTCOLOR='\[\e[0;31m\]'
ENDCOLOR='\[\e[0m\]'
BACKGROUND='\[\e[47m\]'
export PS1="$STARTCOLOR$BACKGROUND\u@\h \t$ENDCOLOR\w>\$?\$ "
```

The `\[ ... \]` is only for surrounding non-printing character sequences, such as colour codes.

Comment: This has worked...almost. Scrolling arrow keys through past commands will now leave a single character after the prompt. While not ideal, it is drastically more manageable then before, while keeping my custom prompt.

Comment: I took off the final ' \\] ' at the and of the prompt (non-printing markers), which seems to have finally solved it entirely.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @Gee_k, and I've removed that unbalanced and unnecessary `\]`. It's strange because I did test before posting and I couldn't get the string to fail

Answer (score 3):

So the issue is that you "overuse" `\[` and `\]`. Those should only be used for non-printable character sequences according to the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html):

```
\[
Begin a sequence of non-printing characters.
This could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt.
\]
```

Additionally, there is a special syntax you need to use so Bash properly renders tabs: `$'\t'`.

So in the end, a more or less fixed version of your prompt code would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly PROMPT_STARTCOLOR='\[\e[0;31m\]'
readonly PROMPT_ENDCOLOR='\[\e[0m\]'
readonly PROMPT_BACKGROUND='\[\e[47m\]'

export PS1="$PROMPT_STARTCOLOR$PROMPT_BACKGROUND\u@\h"$'\t'"$PROMPT_ENDCOLOR\w>$?$"
```

Note that I've renamed your variables to prevent a possible conflict with your environment.

To use the script:

```
source <path_to_file>
```

Related question I asked a while ago: [Prompt customization problem with if clause](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357955/prompt-customization-problem-with-if-clause)

Comment: the \t was for the time. It renders as \t here as a blank area without showing the time. Scrolling with arrow keys for too long here also makes the $ prompt disappear.